# Extending 4x4 deck posts by only 5”

Tags: deck

I have an existing deck that have posts extending from footers under the deck and all the way through for railings. The posts only go up 30” above the deck and I need to add 6” to add new railings. I saw a post about this but they added 12”. Is there a joint that would hold the 6” piece? Can I join it with 3” or is that not sturdy enough to support the top half of the New railing?

Comment: You know that guardrails are required to be 42” high if your deck is 30” above the adjacent grade, unless it’s also a handrail on a stair. (See ICC 1013.2 and 1013.1)

Comment: So that is a thing. Good to know thank you. So in that case I can use the join mentioned in the previous post